# Spring Boot - unable to set JMSReplyTo property

Tags: java, spring-jms

I am trying to use the `convertSendAndReceive` method from Spring's `JmsMessagingTemplate` to use `receiveTimeout`. But it always creates a temp-queue, and it gives me an exception although I set the `JMSReplyTo` property on message (please check code below):

```
TextMessage objectMessage = session.createTextMessage(message);

objectMessage.setJMSCorrelationID(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
objectMessage.setJMSReplyTo(queueOne);
objectMessage.setJMSCorrelationID(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
objectMessage.setJMSExpiration(10L);
objectMessage.setJMSDeliveryMode(DeliveryMode.NON_PERSISTENT);
```

Although, if I use the `convertAndSend` method from `JmsTemplate` then the `JMSReplyTo` property is set properly. Can someone please guide how I can use `receiveTimeout` property so that I can abort slow consumers?

Answer (score 1):

The `JmsTemplate` always uses a temporary reply queue for send and receive operations.

You cannot use your own replyTo.